# Как вывести значение переменной в консоль?

Tags: c, visual-studio

У меня не правильно отображаются числа в консоли (использую язык С). Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

```
int main(void) {
    int i = 1;
    printf("%i", &i);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

[Получаю](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDWVN.png)

> 9894740

P.S. В настройках проекта я указал, чтобы компилировало как C, а не С++

Comment: Пожалуйста, не задавайте вопросы рисунками! Рисунок может быть *иллюстрацией*, но не нужно давать текст как рисунок. Это же так просто - взять текст и перекинуть в вопрос; зачем при этом копия экрана? Только мешает взять ваш текст, сунуть к себе и посмотреть :)

Comment: Еще одно замечание. Не задавайте вопросы типа "У меня неправильно присваивается...", "неправильно работает компилятор...", "не работает С/С++/Java/...". В 99.999% случаев все работает ровно так как Вы написали. Ничего, кроме раздражения, такие вопросы не вызывают.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас попрошено (и получено :)) вывести **адрес** переменной `i`.

Чтобы вывести **значение** `i`, пишите

```
printf("%d\n",i);
```

Comment: Ой блин, забыл, как же стыдно :D
Просто весь курс уже на С++ писали, а тут сказали вернуться к С(((

Comment: @nait123321, вы лукавите - разницы между C и C++ в данном случае никакой нет.

Comment: @PinkTux В С++ я пользуюсь cout, и к нему я более привык.

Comment: @nait123321, и что, в `cout` вы передаёте адрес переменной для того чтобы вывести её значение?